# How come I am able to pass a dataframe into 'dparams' argument in 'geom_qq' function, when it is specified as a 'list' type argument?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How come I am able to pass a **dataframe** into the `dparams` argument of the  `geom_qq()` function, when it is specified as a **list** type argument?

Is it because a **dataframe** is technically a **list** of equal length **vectors**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say so. A data frame can in general be treated like a list, not necessarily the other way around though. 
Without knowing your data, your general idea is correct.

See also:

http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame